# How to prevent yeoman from sending anonymous statistics?

Tags: node.js, yeoman

When the message came up about whether to send anonymous information, I accidentally hit the enter key defaulting to "yes". Now everytime I reinstall/fully remove then install node/yo or execute the yo command, it no longer asks. Is there some file or setting that is hidden in the filesystem that I can manually change such that I do not send anonymous usage statistics to yeoman? is there a configuration file or setting? It is unsettling to know that my usage statistics may be sent while I do not want it to...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The optOut option is kept in `insight-yo.yml`,  which should be in `~\.config\configstore`

Just update the `false` value to `true` and you should be done.

Alternatively, if you delete that file, you'll be presented with the option again and you can answer No manually there.

Comment: On Windows this file is possibly in C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\insight-nodejs\Config\insight-yo.yml