# RUN command in Dockerfile not persisting from container to container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, yo

I am running [yo](http://yeoman.io) in a Docker container and in my Dockerfile, I have the command `RUN echo no | yo doctor`. When yo runs for the first time, it asks for an answer to:

> ====================================================================
>   We're constantly looking for ways to make yo better!
>   May we anonymously report usage statistics to improve the tool over time?
>   More info: https://github.com/yeoman/insight & http://yeoman.io
>   ==================================================================== (Y/n)

Every time, I create a new container, yo is asking me the same question again.
Since each container is being built using the same image and I am running `echo no | yo doctor` in my Dockerfile shouldn't it prevent yo from asking the question again?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19980731/1318694 - Check the contents of `~/.config/configstore` in the image.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I see a RUN using pipe, I try that command in a subshell (`sh -c`)

```
RUN sh -c 'echo no | yo doctor'
```

If it does not work, another workaround would be to include that command in a script, `COPY` the script and `RUN` it.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. The command runs fine when I run docker build. When I create a new container using docker run, yo still asks that question.

Comment: @Shan What is your `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`? What is executed on `docker run`?